# Name for feeling of death of hope

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word (or short phrase) that can be used for the feeling that accompanies the death of (a) hope? Specifically for something long term, like in a failing relationship or other similar loss (friends, jobs, etc.), where there might be multiple "hopes" that can die independently.

I do not feel that "Impending demise" or similar expressions are right, because they are more logical projections, rather than the actual emotion that is felt as a result. Dread also is not correct, because dread implies a fear that is not meant to be present in this usage - the emotion is more of a neutral/muted emption.

Sample:

> As I sat there watching my girlfriend stew in anger, I felt ____ as I realized once again that we were probably heading for a breakup.

This feeling is not about the hope being gone, but more about having had a lot of hope before, and now there is not as much and one more hope just died.

Comment: *Despair* won't do it for you? (I think you're too good for her anyway.)

Comment: @deadrat Despair could work, but its definition says there is no hope left. The feeling I am trying to describe is not total despair, but a little before that point where a ray of hope was just snuffed, but there are still a few more left.

Comment: _On the brink of despair_, then?

Comment: I felt **resignation** as I realised ...

Answer (score 2):

*I felt **resignation** as I realized once again that we were probably heading for a breakup.*

> **resignation**
>   [mass noun] The acceptance of something undesirable but inevitable:
>   ‘a shrug of resignation’
>
> Origin
>   Late Middle English: via Old French from medieval Latin resignatio(n-), from resignare unseal, cancel (see resign).
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resignation

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a word that *exactly* captures what you're looking for. The obvious choices--***despondent, despairing, forlorn, hopeless, disconsolate***--don't quite achieve your intent. Best bet, in my opinion, would be just to add a qualifier of some sort, i.e.:

- As I sat there watching my girlfriend stew in anger, I felt ***that*** ***familiar sense of hopelessness*** as I realized once again that we were probably heading for a breakup.
- As I sat there watching my girlfriend stew in anger, ***the grip of my past despair again took hold*** as I realized we were probably heading for another breakup.
- As I sat there watching my girlfriend stew in anger, I felt ***freshly forlorn*** as I realized once again that we were probably heading for a breakup.

Something along those lines perhaps.

Answer (score -3):

I would probably say 'Despair', or you can also use 'Agony'

Comment: look for synonyms. words like Desolation and despondency can work as well

Comment: I like the word you proposed.  Click on "edit" and add the definition, along with a link to an online definition.